# How to get span title using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, spyder

I have this span:

```
<span class='title'>Model:</span><span class='val'>Galaxy S20 5G</span><br>
```

I want to get 'Galaxy S20 5G'
How would I go about it?

I've already got the content chosen, but I am having trouble printing it out.

I've tried something like this:

```
results = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'val'})
for pr in results:
    print('Name:' +pr.find('span', attrs ={'class':'val'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
spam = "<span class='title'>Model:</span><span class='val'>Galaxy S20 5G</span><br>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(spam, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span', {'class':'val'}).string)
```

output

```
Galaxy S20 5G
```